# Fixed Nav Bar, Broken Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fixed, nav

I'm currently working on a website for work, and I'm trying to get a scrolling/fixed nav bar to work. I'm going off of [this tutorial](http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/simple-steps-for-creating-a-fixed-navigation-bar/), but I can't get mine to fade in/out like in his preview. I've tried everything I can think of short of throwing my computer at a wall. I don't know much Javascript, so that's only adding to the frustration.

I posted a preview of the code [here](http://kadehall.com/preview/fixednav-test/) and I've listed the javascript portion of the code below. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#navigation a, #fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrolltop >= 110) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeIn(100);
    }

    else if(scrolltop <= 110) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeOut(100);
    }
  });
});
```

---

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*BASICS*/
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    margin: 0px !important  ;
}
html{
 /* background-image: url(parts/bg5.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed; */
    background-color: #D1DEF2;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, main, article, figure {
    display: block; 
}

/*HEADER*/
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: -110px auto 0px;
    z-index: 50;
}
    header #header-content{
        width: 1024px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    header #headlogo{
        width: 306px;
        height: 81px;
        background-image:url(parts/header/logo.png);
        background-position: center;
        margin: 21px 0px 25px 32px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-transition: background-position 1s ease;
                transition: background-position 1s ease;
    }

/* NAV */
nav{
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #445476;
    box-shadow-bottom: 0px -1px 5px #212B44;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
            transition: all 1s ease;
    postition: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
    nav .nav-content{
        width: 1024px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    nav .navmain{
        margin: 30px 154px 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #navigation{
        z-index: 10;
    }
    nav #end-leftnav{
        margin-right: 36px;
    }
    nav #start-rightnav{
        margin-left: 123px;
    }
    nav ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Cabin Condensed", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #585858;
    }
    nav li{
        float: left;
    }
    nav .navspot{
        padding: 0px 5px 3px;
        color: inherit;
        margin: 0px 17px;
        color: #585858;
    }
    nav .navspot:hover{
        border-bottom: 3px solid #445476;
    }
    nav .navsoc{
        margin-left: 27px;
    }
    nav .navsoc img{
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 3px 10px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 1s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    }
    nav .navsoc img:hover{
        border-bottom: 0px;
        opacity: .6;
        transition: opacity 1s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    }
    nav #columncircle{
        margin: -30px auto 0px;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        position: absolute;
    /*  border-radius: 100%;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #333333;
        background-color: #445476; */
    }

    /* FIXED NAV EXCLUSIVE */
    #fixedbar { 
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 65px;
        z-index: 100;
        margin-top: -110px;
    }
    #fixednav { 
        display: block;
        margin: -500px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px auto;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav .navfixed{
        margin: 35px 154px 0px;
    }

#filler{
    margin-top: 1000px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `fadeIn` / `fadeOut` function is very fast.

change the speed of it

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#navigation a, #fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrolltop >= 110) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeIn(250);
    }

    else if(scrolltop <= 110) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeOut(250);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed the speed to 250, but it still flashes in and out, rather than fading. Thank you, though. :)

Comment: try changing it to `'slow'` instead of `250`

Comment: I changed it to `slow` and it got rid of the floating nav altogether.

Comment: can you post your css?

Comment: Sure. Edited the first post.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navigation
    left: 0
    top: 0
    z-index: 10
    position: fixed

<body style="margin-top:(height of the navigation bar)px">
```

Comment: That didn't help. It just pushed the header to the bottom of the page and kicked the nav completely. :/

Comment: This will not work for fadein and fadeout but its to make the navigation bar sticky. Same way if you want to fade in and fade out you can achieve that using the css animation property by making opacity from 100 to 0 and vise versa